# What are my code golf languages?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I was curious to find out the answer count for each of the languages I golf in.

Using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, I just wrote a query to answer just that and thought other people might find it interesting.

[Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/revision/301169/390503/my-answer-count-per-language?userId=3527) are my languages. Query with your user id to find out yours.

While we're at it, [here's a list of all the languages on the site](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/revision/301170/390502/code-golf-languages).

The queries are not perfect, and they rely on the answer body to be of the form: `<h?>{LanguageName}?`, where:

- the first `?` can be `1`, `2`, or `3`
- the second `?` can be space, colon, comma, or `<`

*(after some trial and error I noticed these values work in most of the cases)*

Suggestions for improving the queries are welcome.

---

**Edit:** Removed the answers to King-of-the-hill questions (improvement suggested by [steveverrill](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5086/3527))

I also merged the two queries into one, which allows [filtering by a user id](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/revision/301314/390708/code-golf-languages?userId=3527), or specifying `null` to see [all stats](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/revision/301314/390708/code-golf-languages?userId=null).

---

**Edit:** Improved the query by implementing ProgramFOX's suggestion (parse language names when wrapped in `<a>` tags): http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/revision/308877/400000/code-golf-languages

---

**Edit:** Added "Total Score" column (sum of upvotes): http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/revision/308882/400005/code-golf-languages

Answer (score 8):

+1, Very interesting data, unfortunately reliant on how people present their answers.

At the bottom end of the table you can see a lot of KOTH answers with the names of bots being misinterpreted as languages.

But the greatest issue is that Brainfuck is all over the place! There are seperate entries for **`Brainf**k`** and **`Brainf***`** for example. Searchability is a great reason to stop censoring the name of this language!

Ordering by language also reveals the great variety of ways that C and its derivatives are presented. there are over 20 entries, and I'm surprised we have less C++ than C# I wonder if that's correct? Still, good work!

Comment: Less C++ than C# is probably correct. I've seen a lot of answers with Linq, but very few using STL.

Comment: Good point - perhaps I should filter out answers to KOTH questions.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Some of my answers have links in the header, pointing to a wiki page about the used language. It would be nice if these answers are counted as well.

Comment: I'll think of this. Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support Regex and text manipulations such as these can be pretty hard.

Comment: I managed to parse the language names in links. Here's the improved list showing your languages: http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/revision/308877/400000/code-golf-languages?userId=9275

Comment: @w0lf Nice! Adding a [status-completed] tag to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea. I also have some answers that don't have a language for the header (like for a tips page or something) so these can be omitted, in my opinion. Also, some challenges such as KOTH for a specific language have the header as a bot name, instead of a language. These could be fixed by checking posts for a prettify tag declaration that can override a header, since I use [prettify tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) in my code.

Regex to match a prettify tag: `<!--(?:\w)*language(-all)?(?:\w)*:(?:\w)*lang-(.*?)(?:\w)*-->` The first capturing group indicates whether the tag is for the entire post or the next snippet. The second capturing group is the language name or abbreviation (e.g. `js` for JavaScript or `cpp` for C++).

Example tag usage: `<!-- language: lang-python -->`

Comment: Unfortunately, T-SQL (which is the language I used for the query) does not support regex. That's why I resorted to the ugly workarounds you see in my query. With regex, it would have been much easier.

Comment: @w0lf Ah. It does have some regex pattern matching functionality though. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194652/sql-server-regular-expressions-in-t-sql) and [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3341/powershell-and-tsql-regular-expression-examples-for-sql-server/). Not sure how useful that would be in this case though, since there are no capture groups.

Comment: Exactly. The CLR solution is the only one with a rich enough functionality, but it involves running some custom DLLs on the server side, which is not allowed in this case for obvious security reasons.